# How can I remove subquery?

Tags: sql, group-by, subquery, left-join, on-clause

I need to remove the subquery. But I must maintain the condition. What can I do?

```
(SELECT * FROM customer_orders where status=3)


SELECT cus.id,cus.customer_name,cus.mobile,cus.email, 
COUNT(CAST(cus_ord.customer_id AS INT)) AS Total_Order ,SUM(cus_ord.order_total_amt) AS Total_Amount
FROM customers as cus
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM customer_orders where status=3) as cus_ord on CAST(cus_ord.customer_id AS INT)= CAST(cus.id AS INT)
GROUP BY CAST(cus.id AS INT)
```

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: Hi @durloveroy would be good to see some sample data and results.

Comment: Presumably this is MySQL, due to the use of Backticks, and the fact that it has the (in my opinion) bad habit of not all the columns either being aggregated or in the `GROUP BY`; which SQL Server explicitly doesn't allow.

Comment: But `CAST(anything AS INT)` is not allowed in MySql: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast

Comment: /shrug @forpas . The fact that the OP hasn't [edit]ed their question to actually confirm what RDBMS they are really using, doesn't help us help them. If they *are* using SQL Server, then they would be getting *lots* of errors and they've omitted all of them.

Comment: @Larnu I agree. This is why I removed all the irrelevant tags. My comment was meant to prevent the MySql tag. The OP's code works without errors in MariaDB and SQLite but it's up to them to set the correct tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the condition in the `ON` clause:

```
......................
FROM customers AS cus LEFT JOIN customer_orders AS cus_ord 
ON CAST(cus_ord.customer_id AS INT) = CAST(cus.id AS INT) AND cus_ord.status = 3
......................
```

Also:

```
COUNT(CAST(cus_ord.customer_id AS INT))
```

is equivalent to just:

```
COUNT(cus_ord.customer_id)
```